# How to insert number in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, insert, position, sorting

I have an array with numbers like this:

```
25, 19, 14, 11, 9, 7, 5, 2
```

and I want to insert a number at the right position

I wrote this but I don't know if the code is true. Can you help me?

```
if(number > array[i] && number < array[i+1]){
     rightposition = i;
}
```

Is this check true?

Comment: "Is this check true?" -- what do you mean by this? Are you talking about the java concept of boolean truth? In which case that value could be true if number == 5, array[4] == 4, , array[5] == 20.

Comment: can we assume that "true" means "right"?

Answer (score 1):

Use `TreeSet<Integer>` this is a sorted list.

```
Set<Integer> list = new TreeSet<Integer>();
list.addAll(array); // add all the data
```

The sorting happens automatically as you insert the elments, using a Set will remove duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying makes logical sense, but I don't know if it's correct because I don't know what "right position" means for your code. If you could post more of your code, it might be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this portion of code is executing inside a for loop (you may want to post more of your code to ensure we're making the right assumptions).

This code will fail with a NullPointerException if the current element is the last element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you might make your question more clear (how to define "right position"?) There are at least 3 things to consider.

1. Equal items. If you insert 19, your code will work incorrectly. If your origin array is 25 19 19 19 8 5 2, and another 19 is to be inserted, which position you define to be the right position?
2. As your sequence is decreasing, so at least it should be like (number < array[i] && number >= array[i+1])
3. When you insert 1 or 100, which should be inserted at the end or begin of the sequence, the code will work incorrectly.